# What is this tree and will it eventually destroy my house?

Tags: trees

I bought my house last fall. All I knew was this is a Christmas tree. I wrapped it with Christmas lights and it looked merry last winter.

Come spring, it started sprouting new buds rapidly. Now it's summer and it's still sprouting new buds. Its needles look a lot like the 25ft Spruce tree in my front yard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Will this tree grow so big that its roots will destroy my house's foundation?

How do I "control" it? It's "hollow" with no needles inside:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

It's a [Dwarf Alberta Spruce](http://garden.org/learn/articles/view/3363/).  (Well, it's a White Spruce, and because of how dense it is, my money's on Dwarf Alberta, a type of White Spruce.)

Technically, you want at least 3' between one of those and a foundation, but if your foundation's in working order you can get away with 2'.

Only grows to about 10-12 ft.

Like most conifers, it does not produce new growth on old wood, so if you want it pretty, read up on how and when to prune. The dead zone inside the tree is due to sunlight deprivation - it's common on a lot of conifers, and information on how to re-beautify it is easily found. (I'd link some but I gotta get going.)

This year's growth looks a bit stunted. A feeding, with micronutrients (or lime) may be in order.

Good luck.